# Creating a phylogenetic tree with domain annotations using BioPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to create a figure like so:

[Example of figure I would like to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhkJy.png)

Here is some dummy data and attempt so far to go about this:

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Bio import Phylo

# input data
treedata = "(A, (B, C))"
handle = io.StringIO(treedata)
tree = Phylo.read(handle, "newick")
# domains = [[speciesreference, full length of protein sequence, [domain reference code, start position, end position], [speciesreference, full length of protein sequence, [domain reference code, start position, end position]]
domains = [['A', 150, ['IPR000001', 10, 15], ['IPR000002', 20, 40], ['IPR000003', 70, 130]],
           ['B', 300, ['IPR000001', 70, 150], ['IPR000002', 29, 40], ['IPR000003', 100, 200]],
           ['C', 100, ['IPR000001', 5, 15], ['IPR000002', 25, 30], ['IPR000003', 27, 90]]]

# create figure and subplots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=300)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)  # left axis
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, sharey=ax1)  # right axis

# draw dendrogram to axis 1
fig = Phylo.draw(tree, axes=ax1)

# draw rest to axis 2
# ...

# show figure
plt.show()
```

I have been advised to use the matplotlib bar function to plot the domains. How would I go about doing this?

P.s. If there is a much easier way of doing this in another language I am open to it, but I would prefer to do this programatically if possible.

Comment: I think that doing it with matplotlib will be pain... I suggest to try to modify plots with ete3 (I didn't don't think that it provides exactly what you want out of the box, but it is pretty close) http://etetoolkit.org/gallery/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ETE3](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_drawing.html#node-faces) to implement this as well - it can load the tree as a newick, and then you can set it up with the motifs - from how I understand the documentation you'll have to have a list of lists for each organism, like so:

```py
motifs = [[start_of_motif, end_of_motif, motif_shape, motif_width, motif_height,
           foreground_color, font|size|color|label_text],
         [start_of_motif2, end_of_motif2, motif2_shape, motif2_width, motif2_height,
           foreground_color, font|size|color|label2_text]]
```

and so on. 
So for example you could have this as

```py
motifs_a = [[10, 15, "[]", None, 10, "green", "arial|12|black|IPR000001"], 
           [20, 40, "[]", None, 10, "yellow", "arial|12|black|IPR000002"],
           [70, 130, "[]", None, 10, "red", "arial|12|black|IPR000003"]]
```

for your first organism, where `[]` for the shape means it'll be a rectangle.

You then attach it to the relevant organism. Going off ETE3's documentation, that would be:

```py
from ete3 import Tree, SeqMotifFace, add_face_to_node

tree_with_domains = Tree("(A, (B, C))") # or Tree("path/to/newick.nwk")
protein_seq_a = "<your sequence here>" 

motifs_a = [[10, 15, "[]", None, 10, "green", "arial|12|black|IPR000001"], 
           [20, 40, "[]", None, 10, "yellow", "arial|12|black|IPR000002"],
           [70, 130, "[]", None, 10, "red", "arial|12|black|IPR000003"]]

organism_a_motif_face = SeqMotifFace(protein_seq_a, motifs=motifs_a)
(tree_with_domains & "A").add_face(organism_a_motif_face, 0, "aligned")
```

If you don't have the sequence, you can also pass `seq=None` to SeqMotifFace.

Comment: Hello! I'm getting an import error `ImportError: cannot import name 'SeqMotifFace' from 'ete3'`

Comment: How did you install `ete3`? The one big downside is it's *very* particular about the dependencies and then gives import errors. I highly recommend using conda to install it.